# Looping childnodes in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
if(event.target.parentNode.className.indexOf('feat_img')!==1){
    var innodes=event.target.parentNode.firstChild; 



    while(event.target.parentNode.childNodes){
            console.log(innodes);
            if(innodes.className=='img_preview'){
                event.target.parentNode.removeChild(innodes);
            }
            innodes=event.target.parentNode.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working. Am i doing it right?

Comment: The `.nextSibling` of the `.parentNode` is not a node you can `.removeChild` from the parent.

Comment: That's an infinite loop, `.childNodes` is always a truthy object.

Comment: Nope. From the childNode's target event you are getting the parentNode and checking if that parent has childNode and the loop is infinite. Can you post the html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Is this what you are looking for?](https://jsfiddle.net/9bh1p2vh/1/) I loop through the children and remove all img_preview.

```
var outer = document.getElementById('outer');
for (var i = 0; i < outer.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var inner = outer.childNodes[i];
    if (inner.className === 'img_preview') {
        outer.removeChild(inner);
    }
}
```

Note: I changed the loop end condition so we can be fairly sure it terminates (in the original code, if there is a child that isn't `img_preview`, we could get stuck in an infinite loop).

Answer (score 0):

For people looking to use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
var outer = document.getElementById('outer');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(outer, function (item) {
    // do your suff..
});
```